# Netbeans Jmeter "External Edit" not working?

Tags: netbeans, jmeter, netbeans-plugins

I installed **Jmeter** and **Load** **Generator** plugins on my NB. After that i created **"New Jmeter Plan"** in **"Load Generator Scripts"** folder. In every single tutorial i found about using those plugins, there is one way to edit this jmeter plan. It is to right-click it and choose **"External Edit"**, then some editor comes up etc... . Unfortunatelly it's not working for me, when i click this option nothing happens, no idea why. Please help me solve this problem or give me some other way to edit jmeter plans there. I have already spent a lot of time on searching for solution.

Answer (score 3):

Goto %APPDATA%\NetBeans\8.0.1\modules\jmeter\bin

(change the netbeans version as per your netbeans installation, also if you are on unix %APPDATA% is /home/<username>/)

Open a cmd/shell window, and run jmeter.bat from the above directory. Observe warnings/errors and fix appropriately. In my case I had to comment out EVACUATION and PERM shell variables.

Comment: So in following the steps above, I did find that the jmeter.sh file in my APPDATA folder was not marked as executable. I could run it with "bash jmeter.sh" or by chmod'ing it to be executable, but that still hasn't fixed my issue. Not seeing any errors in the Netbeans var/log folder. From the above, I do have to open my JMeter file manually before I can see it.